# how to mount a container to a specific file path?

Tags: linux, mount, docker, container

when we use "-v" argument in "docker run" command, we can specific {src path from host}:{path in container}, e.g

> docker run -v /var/volumns/v1:/var/docker/v1ref ...

but how about mounting a data-only container?

```
docker run --volumes-from data-only-container:<here is mode, ro or rw>
```

how can i achieve the same when using "-v"? can mount to a specific folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, according to the [creating-and-mounting-a-data-volume-container](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/containers/dockervolumes/#creating-and-mounting-a-data-volume-container) and [mount-volumes-from-container-volumes-from](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#mount-volumes-from-container-volumes-from) sections on the Docker site.

The `--volumes-from` options mounts the exposed volumes from the referenced containers at the same location as they were defined. They can't be mounted at a different location.

Example from the Docker site (modified for brevity):

Create a new named container with a volume to share:

`$ docker create -v /dbdata --name dbstore training/postgres /bin/true`

You can then use the `--volumes-from` flag to mount the `/dbdata` volume in another container:

`$ docker run -d --volumes-from dbstore --name db1 training/postgres`